# how to integrate prometheus on kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

This is my prometheus.yml file and i create configmap using `kubectl create configmap prometheus-server-config --from-file=prometheus.yml`

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  evaluation_interval: 5s

scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'goserver'
  scheme: http
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt         
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_servers:
    - 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
    in_cluster: true
    role: pod        
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app]
    regex: goserver
    action: keep        
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_ready]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_ready    
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+)
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: (.+):(?:\d+);(\d+)
    replacement: ${1}:${2}
    target_label: __address__
```

and below is the deployment-prometheus.yaml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: prometheus
        image: prom/prometheus:latest
        args:
          - "-config.file=/etc/prometheus/conf/prometheus.yml"
          # Metrics are stored in an emptyDir volume which
          # exists as long as the Pod is running on that Node.
          # The data in an emptyDir volume is safe across container crashes.
          - "-storage.local.path=/prometheus/"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9090
        volumeMounts:
          - name: prometheus-server-volume
            mountPath: /etc/prometheus/conf/
          - name: prometheus-storage-volume
            mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-server-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus-server-config
        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          emptyDir: {} # containers in the Pod can all read and write the same files here.
```

But whenever i am creating the deployment using `kubectl create -f deployment-prometheus.yaml` the pod status displays CrashLoopBackOff. 
I went through [prometheus-kubernetes example](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml) and i'm running my cluster in minikube.
What should be the cause of this?

Comment: what does `kubectl describe <podname>` show?

Comment: @jaxxstorm, it is very big so you can see on [dpaste](http://dpaste.com/2QTQAYX)

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl logs <podname>`

Comment: Thanks @jaxxstorm i found the problem, actually there was issue with the attributes, in the newer version prometheus doesn't have api_servers field that's why it was causing the problem. and i was using few months old configurations.

Comment: @UtkarshManiTripathi I strongly encourage you to try https://stackoverflow.com/a/52138501/2917986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running the cluster on AWS, the following tutorials work for me https://itnext.io/kubernetes-monitoring-with-prometheus-in-15-minutes-8e54d1de2e13. Let see if you can adapt it. Basicallly, I used helm to install [`coreos/kube-prometheus`](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/helm/kube-prometheus).

`# initialize tiller account
    kubectl create serviceaccount -n kube-system tiller
    kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount kube-system:tiller
    helm init --service-account tiller
    # install Prometheus app
    sleep 1m
    helm repo add coreos https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/coreos-charts/stable/
    helm install coreos/prometheus-operator --name prometheus-operator --namespace monitoring
    helm install coreos/kube-prometheus --name kube-prometheus --namespace monitoring --set global.rbacEnable=true --set prometheus.resources.requests.memory=300Mi
    # forward ports
    kubectl port-forward -n monitoring prometheus-kube-prometheus-0 9090 &
    kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get  pods --selector=app=kube-prometheus-grafana -n  monitoring --output=jsonpath="{.items..metadata.name}") -n monitoring  3000 &
    kubectl port-forward -n monitoring alertmanager-kube-prometheus-0 9093 &`

Answer (score 1):

**Oneliner**

```
kubectl apply --filename https://raw.githubusercontent.com/giantswarm/kubernetes-prometheus/master/manifests-all.yaml
```

**Pre-Requisite**

```
kubectl create namespace monitoring
```

**Outcome**

1. Prometheus Server
2. Service Endpoint for Prometheus Dashboard
3. Alert Manager config

**Reference**

https://github.com/giantswarm/kubernetes-prometheus#quick-start

@Utkarsh Mani Tripathi

Comment: Thanks @suryakrupa , i resolved the problem, there was an issue with the configuration, which was changed in the latest versions. This repo you have given is also good place to start.